# Database Connection .NET MVC

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning the basics of .NET, using the MVC model. It seems simple enough, except for connecting my models to a local database, where I have been having nothing but trouble.

Whatever I screwed up, I don't seem to be able to connect my project (or any other projects) to my database using connection strings, and when I try to Add>New Item> SQL Server Database I get an error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.)
```

Unfortunately, this problem has been hard to diagnose, as I am mostly unfamiliar with Windows Server.

Right now, I have only one model in my application "GetQuestions"

Here are my connection strings:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\{{myusername}}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\master.mdf;Initial Catalog=GetQuestions;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="QuestionsDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\{{myusername}}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0\master.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I'm hoping that this is simply a noob mistake which can easily fix. I have looked at several general walkthroughs but nothing seems to work.

I have screenshots of my Server Explorer and Server Object Explorer that can probably help diagnose this problem, but Stackoverflow will not allow me to post them.

Comment: Do you have a SQL Server installed?

Comment: You tried (local)\v11.0... ?

Comment: Sounds like your `mdf` file does not exist (or your path is incorrect in the connection string).

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes I do. Microsoft SQL Server 2014. And it appears to be connected to this server. Is there a way I could PM you a screenshot of my Server Explorer? I think it would make things much easier

Comment: You could post a link in the comments.

Comment: @crashmstr I believe this is the case also. However, I can't seem to find where my mistake is. It seems to me that I have everything set up correctly. For this reason, I think that I must have made some minor error somewhere that I am unaware of.

Comment: http://uploadpie.com/jS1CT
http://uploadpie.com/5rCQF

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Replace the two connection string you currently have. Moreover, change the database path where it is located.

```
   <add name="QuestionsDBConntext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\master.mdf;Initial Catalog=GetQuestions;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```